# How to check if specific column of selected row in Datagridview is null?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I am checking if the selected row's cell 7,8,9 is null or not. However it only display "enabled" even when all of the cell's value are null. Here is my code

```
 private void btnTest_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvReceivingproducts.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[7].Value != null && row.Cells[8].Value != null && row.Cells[9].Value != null)
            {

               lblchecker.Text = "enabled";

            }
            else
            {
                lblchecker.Text = "disabled";

            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: As @PabloJ suggests in his answer, try checking against `DbNull.Value` instead of `null`

Comment: is my answer acceptable for you?

Answer (score 1):

There could be two faults in this code:

1. The one mentioned by all answers above

2. **Do you realize that lblchecker.Text will have a value corresponding to only the last row in your GridView??** (your logic seems incorrect, are you trying to set a value for each row? because now this is not what the code results in.)

Some good-practice suggestions:

1. Avoid using indexes. What if you later rearrange columns? Try using column names instead

2. A better approach would be to use DataKeys

3. And even better approach would be if this "enabled"/"disabled" value is pre-calculated i.e. prior to data binding. May be you could do this in SQL, or in your Business Layer. It depends on the logic behind this

**UPDATE:**
You could indicate "enabled" value per row if you set a value within each row. Using your code, a possible approach could be something like that:

```
private void btnTest_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvReceivingproducts.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[7].Value != null && row.Cells[8].Value != null && row.Cells[9].Value != null)
        {
            row.Cells[X].Value = "enabled";
        }
        else
        {
            row.Cells[X].Value = "disabled";
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Yes i think this checks only the last rows sir. What i need is to check every row how can i achieve that sir? Ill take note of your good practice sir in the future thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Convert.IsDBNull()` instead of `!=null`

Answer (score 0):

you could try this::

```
    if ((row.Cells[7].Value != null && row.Cells[8].Value != null && row.Cells[9].Value != null) 
     || (row.Cells[7].Value != DBNull.Value && row.Cells[8].Value != DBNull.Value && row.Cells[9].Value != DBNull.Value))
    {
        lblchecker.Text = "enabled";
    }
    else
    {
        lblchecker.Text = "disabled";
    }
```

If do not function use the IsNullOrWhitespace function to test:

`String.IsNullOrWhitespace(row.Cells[8].Value... )`

Comment: Its working but not completely. It is displaying "disabled" when all of the row and its column are blank and enabled when all of the row and its column have values. But if for Example there are 3 rows. Row 1 and 2 have null or blank values in their column 7,8,9, But Row 3 have values on its 7,8,9 column. The text is displaying "enabled". What i want is it will only display enabled when all of the Row and their column 7,8,9 is not null or blank.